# How do I create a secure Conda Environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I want to create a conda env that needs some sort of password to be accessed and altered.
Once created one needs a special set as rights (such as admin) to be able to use and/or alter the env

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you can explain that, it might help develop some answers

Comment: We share some computers between multiple users in our lab, they use the computers to perform their experiments, process the collected data and run some especific code depending on their work. We want to secure the environment aggainst people downloading unwanted packages or altering existing ones, so that our base code will always run smoothly. Basicaly the users can use the env and run their codes in it, but can't alter it in any way.

Comment: Put it in a directory where only the root user has write permissions. You can create environments in a particular prefix with the `-p` or `--prefix` command line flag.

Comment: What permissions should I deny from the user in order for him be able to use jupyter normally but he can't install or uninstall any packages? I'm using windows.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure, I'm not a Windows administrator so I don't know that much about how permissions are done on Windows. I think if you use the Anaconda installer and install it for "All Users" that will put the base environment into the Program Files directory which only the administrator should be able to write to. Then you can try to run Jupyter Notebook and see what happens.